Change the absolute value of elements in a dataframe without changing their sign (+ / -)
I have a dataframe of cumulative changes, which I am trying to convert into (multiplicative) factor values.
If all values were positive, I could simply add 1: e.g. a 25% increase would be 0.25, adding 1 would give me a factor of 1.25, which is correct.
However I have some negative values, these need a subtraction of 1 to be correct e.g. a 25% reduction would be -0.25, subtracting 1 would give me the correct factor or -1.25.
For example with the following dataframe:
  col1  col2
1 0.12 -0.06
2 0.05  0.09

df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0.12, 0.05), col2 = c(-0.06, 0.09))

I would like to get
  col1  col2
1 1.12 -1.06
2 1.05  1.09


if you have a number and decrease it by 25% of itself. wouldn't the multiplicative factor be 0.75 rather than -1.25 ?

yes, apologies - that was a poor example. sign is what I was looking for.

but I'm questioning if you really want to use sign to take -0.06 to -1.06, or if it wouldnt be mathematically correct to have it go to 0.94

You can simply run
> df + sign(df)
  col1  col2
1 1.12 -1.06
2 1.05  1.09

or
> (1 + abs(df)) * sign(df)
  col1  col2
1 1.12 -1.06
2 1.05  1.09

or
> df + 2 * (df > 0) - 1
  col1  col2
1 1.12 -1.06
2 1.05  1.09


Very clean. I thought sign(df) would return a matrix and df + matrix would return matrix which are both wrong...

@s_baldur yes, that is an interesting point. When I looked into the R help manual, I found a statement that might be related: "The rules for determining the attributes of the result are rather complicated. Most attributes are taken from the longer argument. Names will be copied from the first if it is the same length as the answer, otherwise from the second if that is."

@s_baldur and also: "If the arguments are the same length, attributes will be copied from both, with those of the first argument taking precedence when the same attribute is present in both arguments. For time series, these operations are allowed only if the series are compatible, when the class and tsp attribute of whichever is a time series (the same, if both are) are used. For arrays (and an array result) the dimensions and dimnames are taken from first argument if it is an array, otherwise the second."

Thanks. I guess my intuition to use lapply() is not bad when determining the attributes of the result are rather complicated. Seems to be slightly more efficient as well.

@s_baldur no, lapply is not bad and I think it is the safest way to achieve the desired output.

df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) x + sign(x))

df
#   col1  col2
# 1 1.12 -1.06
# 2 1.05  1.09

With dplyr
mutate(df, across(everything(), \(x) x + sign(x)))


good use of sign, and you can use it over the entire df, indeed.

Map function can also be used for this task. The code looks pretty clean.
df[] <- Map(`+`, df, sign(df))

  col1  col2
1 1.12 -1.06
2 1.05  1.09

